# JqGrid Form Edit Validate all fields on Submit and Show error on each invalid field

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid form Edit with templating from the link in
 [Here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/edit_template/index.html)

I have updated the template to look like below sothat I show invalid error below each field if any error.

```
            template = "<div style='margin-left:15px;'><div> Customer ID <sup>*</sup>:</div><div> {CustomerID} </div>";
            template += "<div> Company Name: </div><div>{CompanyName} </div>";
            template += "<div> Phone: </div><div>{Phone} </div>";
            template += "<label for="Phone" class="error ui-state-error-text hidden"></label>";
            template += "<div> Postal Code: </div><div>{PostalCode} </div>";
            template += "<label for="PostalCode" class="error ui-state-error-text hidden"></label>";            
            template += "<div> City:</div><div> {City} </div>";
            template += "<label for="City" class="error ui-state-error-text hidden"></label>";  
            template += "<hr style='width:100%;'/>";
            template += "<div> {sData} {cData}  </div></div>";
```

Now I have added validation to some of my fields using 
[jqgrid Edit Rules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules)

Lets say I have

```
editrules : { required: true} in Phone
editrules : { integer: true} in PostalCode
editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: myCustomCheck } in Country
```

Where my custom check is

```
  myCustomCheck = function (value, colname) {
        if (colname === "County") {
            var label = $("label[for='" + colname + "']");

            if (value.indexOf("foobar") > -1) {
                invalidDesc = true;
                $("#FrmGrid_mygrid").find('#' + colname).addClass("ui-state-error");

                label.html("Country cant be contain foobar");
                label.removeClass('hidden');
                return [false];
            }
            else
            {
                label.addClass('hidden');
                return [true];
            }

        }
        return [true];
    };
```

The issue with here is it marks one input at a time when I click submit and there is no way to show my custom error label, on those edit rules predefined by jqgrid(like the integer/required). It only shows the error at the top of the form.

What I would want is when the user clicks submit I validate all the inputs and show the error message on all the invalid ones instead of showing one click submit then show another...etc

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: I had that tag incase the jqgrid does not support it and jquery validate is an alternative solution.

Comment: That's not the proper way to use tags.  They should only reflect the content of the question to avoid being considered tag-spam.

Comment: @Amete There is similar issue described in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to my problem I have added a hidden error label below each input in the form template as follows

```
            template = "<div style='margin-left:15px;'><div> Customer ID <sup>*</sup>:</div><div> {CustomerID} </div>";
            template += "<div> Company Name: </div><div>{CompanyName} </div>";
             template +=  <label for="CompanyName" class="error ui-state-error-text hidden"></label>
            template += "<div> Phone: </div><div>{Phone} </div>";
            template +=  <label for="Phone" class="error ui-state-error-text hidden"></label>          
            template += "<div> Postal Code: </div><div>{PostalCode} </div>";
            template +=  <label for="PostalCode" class="error ui-state-error-text hidden"></label>                      
            template += "<div> City:</div><div> {City} </div>";
            template += "<label for="City" class="error ui-state-error-text hidden"></label>";         
            template += "<hr style='width:100%;'/>";
            template += "<div> {sData} {cData}  </div></div>";
```

Changed the rules to be all custom

```
editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: emptyCheck } in Phone
editrules : { custom: true, custom_func: numberCheck } in PostalCode
editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: myCustomCheck } in Country
```

WHERE the custom functions are defined as follows. All that happens in the custom checks is check if something is valid and display the error label if it is not valid and return **true** regardless. Returning false in the custom check was the main problem of the validation not able to continue to the next field.

```
   // Add a global field invalid which would summarize the validation result
    var invalid = false;
 emptyCheck = function (value, colname) {

var label = $("label[for='" + colname + "']");
var input = $("#FrmGrid_grdEquipment").find('#' + colname);
    if (value) {
        label.addClass('hidden');
        input.removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
    else {
        input.addClass("ui-state-error");
        label.html(colname+"is required");
        label.removeClass('hidden');
        invalid = true;
        // return [false, " Please correct the errors"];
    }

    return [true];
```

};

```
numberCheck = function (value, colname) {
    var label = $("label[for='" + colname + "']");
    var input = $("#FrmGrid_grdEquipment").find('#' + colname);
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value)) {
        label.addClass('hidden');
        input.removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
    else {
        input.addClass("ui-state-error");
        label.html(colname + "should be number");
        label.removeClass('hidden');
        invalid = true;
        // return [false, " Please correct the errors"];
      }

    return [true];
};


myCustomCheck = function (value, colname) 
{
    // check validation display the error label if not valid       
    return [true];
};
```

Finally add this to the  options for the Edit Dialog

```
onclickSubmit: function ((params, posdata) {   
if (invalid)
    {
        invalid = false;
        return;
    }
      // Else save row and do other stuff
}
```